# K8S synchronization between deployments which use the same secret

Tags: kubernetes

In my k8s cluster I have two deployments: one for generating JWTs using a given key-pair and another one for validating JWTs using the same key-pair.
Both deployments using the same k8s secret which contains the key/pair.
When I want to revoke/update that key pair, how do I create consistency between the deployments? Practically, I want that all the generated JWTs will be validated although there are two different microservices, and not necessarily all the pods of both microservices will be updated at once for using the new keys.
How do I prevent such false alarms of validation failures?

Comment: Why not use the same secret for both?

Comment: (that does require running both in the same namespace)

Comment: I actually use the same secret. after I update the secret I do rollout update to both deployments. but the pods from both deployments aren't in sync - and then theoretically a user can get a jwt from a pod that wasn't updated, and than when he goes to validate it - K8S could potentially redirect his request to a "new" pod (with the new secret) - and his request will fail. How could I prevent it?

Comment: @YosiKarl rotation of secrets is generally implemented in a way when both ends (or at least the receiving one) support both versions for some time.

Comment: I agree, but how do I solve a race in which a JWT was generated by one of the pods that using the new key and the following request (that contains the JWT) was sent to one of the pods which uses the old key?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to have a generic solution for this problem: you must coordinate all the parties yourself.

The common solution is to issue a new secret and let all the participants to accept both.

Then after some time to stop issuing the old version and remove it from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In your Helm chart or Kustomize manifest, set a hash of the contents of the secret as an annotation on pod template, that will automatically trigger a re-deployment when the contents of the secret changes.

Alternatively your software could detect the changes in the files and reload them.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem with the race that happens half-way through deployment rollout.

Comment: There isn't really a solution to that other than to set up a better key rotation system. Rather than a single signing key, have one active key and multiple allowed keys. The issuer only issues using the active key, but the checker will allow any allowed key. So when changing keys you move the active to allowed, and then make a new active key.

Comment: "There isn't really a solution to that other than to set up a better key rotation system" --- that's my very point: your solution suggests something that is broken from the beginning.

Comment: Indeed (while it's sold like a silver bullet) :-)